# PHP Page populated by MySQL dropdowns

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to write a script to display records from an SQL database, but based on three variables which are set by three dropdown boxes on the page which are auto-populated from the database.

This is for a Learning Management System I am working on to provide effective feedback from online learning tests.

The code I am currently working on is below, along with the pseudo code which I hope will explain my requirements. The problem I am having is I cannot get the dropdown boxes to populate based on the criteria I have set in my pseudo code.

Any help is very much appreciated, 
Thank you

John

```
// I used this article for the structure of the following script: 
http://forums.devarticles.com/mysql-development-50/drop-down-menu-populated-from-a-mysql-database-1811.html 

// Dropdown Box 1 - Choose the course - Show entries from the column "Name" from table "mdl_scorm". Once an option has been selected set variable $coursechoice to the value in the "id" column of the "mdl_scorm" table 

// Dropdown Box 2 - Choose the user - Show entries from the columns "firstname" + "lastname" from table "mdl_user" IF the number shown in the "id" column of table "mdl_user" is present in the "userid" column of table "mdl_scorm_scoes_track" AND IF $coursechoice is present in the "scormid" column of table "mdl_scorm_scoes_track". Once an option has been selected set variable $userchoice to the value in the "id" column of table "mdl_user" 

// Dropdown Box 3 - Choose the attempt - Show entries from the column "attempt" from table "mdl_scorm_scoes_track" IF $coursechoice is present in the "scormid" column of the table "mdl_scorm_scoes_track" AND IF $userchoice is present in the "userid" column of table "mdl_scorm_scoes_track". Once an option has been selected set variable $attemptchoice to the value in the "attempt" column from table "mdl_scorm_scoes_track" 

// Submit button displays the records from table "mdl_scorm_scoes_track" which have a value in the column "scormid" which matches $coursechoice AND have a value in the column "userid" which matches $userchoice AND have a value in the column "attempt" which matches $attemptchoice 

$sql="SELECT name FROM mdl_scorm"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$id=$row["id"]; 
$thing=$row["name"]; 
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing; 
} 
?> 
<SELECT NAME=course> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose the course 
<?=$options?> 
</SELECT> 
<?php 

$sql="SELECT username FROM mdl_user"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$id=$row["id"]; 
$thing=$row["name"]; 
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing; 
} 
?> 
<SELECT NAME=user> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose the user 
<?=$options?> 
</SELECT> 
<?php 

$sql="SELECT attempt FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$id=$row["id"]; 
$thing=$row["name"]; 
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing; 
} 
?> 
<SELECT NAME=attempt> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose the attempt 
<?=$options?> 
</SELECT> 
<?php 

$finalresult = SELECT element, value FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track WHERE scormid=$coursechoice AND userid=$userchoice AND attempt=$attemptchoice 
while ($testrows = mysqli_fetch_array($finalresult)){ 
echo $testrows['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommendation below will get your dropdowns working... To actually pull information dynamically based on the dropdowns will require a form, a submit button and some parsing of the $_POST variable.

One step at a time, lets get your dropdowns working.

First, don't forget to close your options with `</option>` after .$thing:

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing."</OPTION>";
```

and

```
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose the course</OPTION>
```

In addition, you are only selecting the name, if you want the id you need to select that too.

```
$sql="SELECT name, id FROM mdl_scorm";
```

and finally, to use the results of the query as an associative array you need mysql_fetch_assoc

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

That last was was probably what was tripping you up most.

Hope that helps.